# ¿Qué sentido tiene la expresión "mejorando lo presente"?

Tags: modismos, expresiones, cortesía

Imaginemos que vamos tres personas por la calle: dos chicos y una chica. De repente nos cruzamos con una chica la mar de guapa y ambos chicos decimos "*uau, qué guapa*". Ante la certidumbre de que el comentario pueda sentar algo mal a nuestra amiga, añadimos "*... **mejorando lo presente***".

Esta expresión la oigo con cierta frecuencia en España y se entiende bien: X es fantástico, pero no tanto como Y, que es con quien estamos. Es decir, valoramos la cualidad determinada (belleza, lo que sea) de la persona X que hemos visto, pero no por ello dejamos de valorar la de la persona Y a quien tenemos al lado y con quien no queremos ser groseros.

Vale, entendido. Ahora bien, ¿por qué la forma de expresarlo es tan rara? Cuando la oí por primera vez de pequeño me pareció que quería decir precisamente lo contrario: X tiene tal cualidad, pero la valoro especialmente porque la persona Y que está conmigo no la tiene para nada. Es decir, una pura grosería.

¿Cómo una expresión así puede haber llegado a tener tal significado? Es cortés usarla en España, pero ¿se entendería en otros países de habla hispana?

Comment: Me encanta que hagas esta pregunta, porque a mí me pasa exactamente lo mismo. Al principio pensaba que la otra persona mejoraba a la que estaba presente, y no al revés.

Comment: Nunca me había parado a pensarlo, pero es verdad que el sentido debería ser el opuesto. Yo soy de España y sí que se dice (aunque es más de generaciones más viejas).

Yo lo veo como un "remiendo" a un comentario en el que se ha metido la pata y todo el mundo sabe que ha sido así, pero se acepta para "quitar hierro"...

Comment: Yo creo que la frase debe ser. ''Qué guapa chica, no mejorando lo presente'', con lo cual queda de manifiesto que la chica que va contigo no se sienta menospreciada, pero si lo quieres decir como piropo a la mujer que va pasando sería ''Qué guapa chica, mejorando lo presente, aunque en este caso la chica que va contigo te dará un codazo mínimo por tu grosería para con ella.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La frase original era *mejorándolo **lo** presente*.

La repetición de la silaba *lo* era de difícil pronunciación y al pronunciarse puede entenderse como *mejorando lo presente*. Si no, prueben a pronunciar *mejorándolo lo presente* y se darán cuenta que suena como *mejorando lo presente* si se dice de forma rápida.

Así que ante la dificultad de pronunciarlo correctamente y ante el sonido que no se distinguía, se extendió el uso de *mejorando lo presente* sin más.

Lo leí por algún sitio en Internet y creo que es la explicación más convincente.

Comment: Eso tiene mucho más sentido, estaría bien si pudieras encontrar una fuente fiable de esa explicación.

Comment: Gran respuesta. Añado este [este enlace al blog de Antonio Ferrán de la cierva](http://www.ferrandelacierva.com/mejorando-lo-presente/), que explica, como dice esta respuesta que "tal y como apunta Rafael Cerro, es un derivado de la fórmula original «mejorándolo lo presente», que sí tiene pleno sentido cuando se quiere decir «ella es guapa, pero usted lo es más». Se trata, pues, de una haplología, ya que se ha eliminado una sílaba semejante a otra contigua, debido a la dificultad de pronunciar este cumplido en su forma primitiva"

Comment: Esta respuesta habla del origen pero no responde a ¿Qué sentido tiene la expresión? Las otras dos respuestas si lo hacen.

Answer (score 5):

La intención del hablante con ese *mejorando lo presente* es clara: da a entender (aunque sea de forma fingida) que cree que *lo presente* (sea una o sean más personas) mejora (supera, [aunque no es un significado reconocido en el DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Onrxgkw)) al alabado en la frase anterior. Pero a veces (más de las que nos gustaría) una intención no se expresa con claridad.

Supongamos que la frase es:

> Esa chica es muy guapa... mejorando lo presente.

Pongo los puntos suspensivos porque lo normal es que se haga una pausa, pero una coma serviría, según la entonación. ¿Por qué es ambigua la frase?

El gerundio, atendiendo a si tiene sujeto propio o no, admite dos construcciones:

1. Si comparte el sujeto con la oración principal nos encontramos con un gerundio **conjunto** o **concertado**: *Siendo tan grosero, acabarás mal*. El sujeto de *acabarás* y de *siendo* es *tú*.
2. Si el gerundio tiene un sujeto propio, que no es ni el sujeto ni el objeto directo de la oración principal, es un gerundio **absoluto** o **no concertado**: *Despuntando el día, el labriego se levantó*. El sujeto de *despuntando* es *el día*, mientras que el de *se levantó* es *el labriego*.

En el primer caso, si el gerundio es pospuesto, puede prescindirse de la coma (*Acabarás mal siendo tan grosero*), aunque si el gerundio queda muy alejado del verbo principal se aconseja mantenerla. En el segundo caso, esté donde esté la frase del gerundio, hay que separarla con comas. La frase no puede escribirse (o entonarse) así: [image]*El labriego se levantó despuntando el día*. Parecería que es el labriego el que hace salir el sol al levantarse o mientras se levanta.

Esta frase hecha es un caso de gerundio no concertado. *Esa chica* es el sujeto de *es* y *lo presente* de *mejorando*. ¿Podría ser concertado? Si eliminamos la pausa la frase queda forzada, pero como siempre puede añadirse, es posible la interpretación. Es este caso, *lo presente* sería objeto directo de *mejorar* y es la chica (el sujeto compartido) la que mejora *lo presente*.

Otra fuente de ambigüedad es el hecho de usar el neutro *lo*, que cosifica a la persona referida. Si no fuera así, no habría lugar para el error, porque habría que decir *mejorando a la (persona) presente*.

Answer (score 4):

En Argentina alguna vez la he oído, más o menos con el mismo significado. Pero tampoco es fácil justificarla, parece un sinsentido. Se [aduce](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/mejorando-lo-presente.911860/) que, en  la oración subordinada "... mejorando lo presente", "lo presente" es un sujeto; con lo cual una paráfrasis aproximada sería *"... dando por supuesto que lo aquí presente mejora (es decir, supera) lo dicho"*. A mí la explicación me resulta un poco artificiosa.

Comment: Mucho mejor que la respuesta aceptada.!!

Answer (score 0):

La última respuesta es la correcta. No tiene que ver con "mejorándolo" o una rápida pronunciación. Es una construcción antigua del gerundio: mejorando lo presente = lo presente lo mejora... O sea mejorando. ¿el qué? lo presente.